# Chart.JS not working in Xpages, chart not defined errror

Tags: chart.js, xpages

I'm trying to use chart.js in an xpage
(example from chart.js website)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'line',
  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
    }]
  },
  // Configuration options go here
  options: {}
});
</script>
</xp:view>
```

Chart.js and jquery are loading , but I get an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined

and also

> Error: multipleDefine at _f (dojo.js:15) at _f9 (dojo.js:15) at def (dojo.js:15) at jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 at jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 at jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2

Why do I get both those errors ?

Comment: It's an AMD module loader issue. See other answers on how to fix this :-)

Answer (score 0):

I added my resources in a differend way, and now it seems to work .
Thank you for Per Henrik Lausten to point me in the good direction

```
   <xp:this.resources>
   <xp:headTag tagName="script">
   <xp:this.attributes>
    <xp:parameter name="type" value="text/javascript" />
    <xp:parameter name="src" value="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" />
   </xp:this.attributes>
  </xp:headTag>

  <xp:headTag tagName="script">
   <xp:this.attributes>
    <xp:parameter name="type" value="text/javascript" />
    <xp:parameter name="src" value="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0" />
   </xp:this.attributes>
  </xp:headTag>
 </xp:this.resources>
```